Consider a car going to a level curve while coasting(by disengaging clutch) is there any situation in which the speed of the car will increase?
Consider a car going to a level curve while coasting(by disengaging clutch) is there any situation in which the speed of the car will increase? (neglect the air resistence, assume the coefficient of friction remains the same everywehre, maybe is a caroverflow question)

What do YOU think?

Is there a tailwind? Magnets in the car ahead?

What does "going to a level curve" mean precisely? If it means driving along a level curve, then the answer must necessarily be no, since no change will happen along a level curve.

Take a moment to think about the actions happening in this scenario. What forces are really contributing to this car? The main thing to note here is that the car is on a level curve. There is no engine power, no pushing, and no external forces. Gravity can't contribute because it's a level curve. Ultimately, you arrive at a situation where there isn't anything pushing or wanting to accelerate this car. So, the car's speed won't increase.

One can indeed create a force acting on the car by reducing the turn radius.

@paulina, your comment is correct! You can create a force on a car by reducing the turn radius, but at no point does that cause an increase in velocity. Considering this is one idea scenario, if you look at F = mv^2/r, reducing the radius only increases the required centripetal force. This force changes the direction of the velocity, not velocity itself.

If the road is on a giant turntable, centrifugal force will throw the car outward. If the car has outward velocity and the road curves so the car goes against the direction of rotation, Coriolis force will accelerate it.
